# RichTextEditor(WYSIWYG) error on MVC4 Nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I have installed RichTextEditor(WYSIWYG) through NugetPackage for my MVC4 Razor application. Build is succeeded but i am getting the below Runtime error. Do i need to add any license file, i could not find file any where. Pls provide if it is available for free.
Exception:
"""An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.LicenseException' occurred in RichTextEditor.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: License file not found"""

Thanks,
Sarath

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the project site and look at the downloads page.
http://richtexteditor.com/download.aspx

It appears that they offer a 30 day trial. I'm not sure if that's the one that the nuget package installs, but it would appear as though this is not a free utility, and will require some sort of licensing to use in your application.

Here's some more information on their licensing info. http://richtexteditor.com/license.aspx

This particular rich text editor doesn't seem to be very easy to deal with. Might I suggest one of these instead? I've used both and they both work well.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TinyMCE/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ckeditor3/